# What's with the hostility about how big Minecraft is?

Tags: discussion, closing

[How big is the Minecraft Universe compared to real life?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/256002/112)

I was really surprised by the reaction to this question. It was hugely downvoted, and gathered many close votes. Comments on the question by high rep users indicated it was "nonsense", and "a thought experiment".

None of this is correct. Minecraft has a finite scale, and a finite size. It has a well defined boundary. There is a [detailed wiki article](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/World_border) about the behaviour of the game at the boundary. You can travel to the boundary. If you were building something at the boundary, you would certainly discover that its existence was relevant to your game play experience. And if you were planning to build something bigger than 60 million blocks on a side, you're out of luck.

These are interesting, objective facts. Can we please be a little less trigger-happy with the judgement, especially on topics we aren't experts in?

As a side-note, I flagged the misleading comment train for deletion, but other than my own comment, nothing was cleaned up.

Comment: Really? 3 negative votes and not a single comment? This is the meta, isn't it? Discussion is what it's for, right?

Comment: Downvotes are probably two fold. On meta downvotes often mean disagreement. Also, downvotes may be due to (at least from my reading and interpretation) a bit of an accusatory tone to the post. Especially with your second to last statement there.

Comment: Accusatory? Yes, I suppose it is. After all, one of the commenters said  
_I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a thought experiment and has no bearing to gameplay._ Which is a pretty clear demonstration of how inexpert they are about this topic. Or am I missing something?

Comment: As to the disagreement, great! Let's discuss the disagreement. I'd love to see the explanation for why this question is "nonsense".

Comment: It was discussed in the comments on the question. The users voiced their opinions there and reopening the discussion does no good other than simply stirring up trouble and, from my perspective, trying to pick a fight.

Comment: Wow. Raising a discussion is "picking a fight"? Not sure what to say to that.

Comment: Hi, I'm one of the users who downvoted this question. I did so because it *is* nonsense. A minecraft world is *boundless* as of Beta 1.8, so accounting for the size of an entire world doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @unionhawk - how do you figure that? Can you point to an external reference?  I'd love to read it.

Comment: "The Far Lands terrain generation and most bugs and glitches were fixed as of Beta 1.8." - [the wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Far_Lands)

Comment: @unionhawk - read the link in my answer, to the wiki, about the world boundary. Then tell me what you think.

Comment: here's the link for convenience: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/World_border

Comment: Hmm. You appear to be right. There is a boundary apparently. Be that as it may, while I agree it's on-topic, it's still not a good question by virtue of being a thought experiment

Comment: @unionhawk - How can it be a thought experiment, when I can travel there and experience it? How can it be metaphysical when there's an entire wiki article about the behaviour of items at this boundary? I appreciate it's an obscure topic, but really that's the point. The decisions made about this question were made without really understanding the situation.

Comment: @ire_and_curses A reason people might be downvoting this meta is because it's mostly just a complaint about downvotes. People might be downvoting your Minecraft question because it's Friday, or they had a bad lunch, or whatever. We can't control how people downvote. You don't seem like you really want to hear their reasons for downvoting... they've given them to you. You want to *argue* with their reasons. That's pretty pointless. Now, on the other hand, if the question was closed and this meta had been about how it should be opened instead of closed, that would be a valid meta topic.

Comment: I see you're discussing about my question.

Comment: @ire_and_curses - On top of what Sterno says in the comment above, the site is primarily community-run, and there are definitely many camps that have formed which have different opinions on how the site should be run. In this case, you've come across one of the more vocal ones that think questions that *'aren't useful'* or have *'no utility'* should not be allowed here, even if they fall well into our on-topic areas. Not everyone agrees with this stance and it's definitely a grey area as to where that line should be drawn. At the end of the day, votes are still individual though.

Comment: @JimJones - Welcome to the party, we seem to do this every week or so :)

Comment: @Robotnik actually, I've already been here. I just changed my username you see, my previous was just Jim. Also changed my password and email address.

Answer (score 7):

There was disagreement about the question because we are a large and diverse group of people with lots of different view points and experiences. Some felt the question should be closed, others wanted it to be open. The community voted and it has stabilized at open. At least for now.

This is just how things work on this site sometimes. We won't always agree, and we have those discussions. Sometimes those discussions happen in the comments, sometimes they happen in chat, and sometimes they get moved to meta. This particular one happened in the comments. Views and opinions were expressed on both sides relating to what should happen to the question, and action was taken accordingly.

The privileges are granted to users according to their experience for the reason of being able to self moderate these disagreements. The system is designed so that the community can help decide if content belongs here or not (with some guidance from SE sometimes). Users who have enough experience in working with the site and knowing what fits and what doesn't can help filter out the content and improve the site. When users disagree, we can come to a community consensus through voting.

**Basically, this is the site working exactly as it was intended to**

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain how SO works, but it's not really necessary. :) My point is broader than the site mechanics. It's that there's something clearly wrong with the way this question was treated, and the way it has ended up now. Case in point, I just got a downvote on my answer, presumably by someone who doesn't like this _meta_ question!

Comment: The question was treated in the same way as so very many other questions are treated: by a user examining it and deciding if it is a good fit for the site or not. A few users thought it was not a good fit, left a note why they didn't think it was a good fit, and voted to close. Other users disagreed, voiced their opinion, and voted accordingly. Again, nothing about the treatment of this question was different from how we treat any other question, nor do I feel it was handled inappropriately (and I was the initiator on reopening it).

Comment: Generally speaking, in community run sites - there's usually a collection of guidelines and direction decided upon, for said community - to guide them in the right direction when it comes to voting and voting to close. 

Otherwise, you end up with the equivalent of a youtube comment section, where there's no rhyme or reason, leaving askers to hope their question doesn't get downvoted to oblivion or closed, just because there's an outbreak of cereal urination going on amongst the community. 

In short - if there isn't direction, the voting system is meaningless.